# black screen and blinking carrot after trying to install gnome

Tags: boot, 20.04, gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I was trying to install GNOME on Ubuntu Focal. However, after a reboot I'm getting a black screen with blinking carrot. I did the following (probably dumb) steps te get to this point.

1. I ran `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`
2. Rebooted, saw no changes and removed with `sudo apt remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop`
3. Ran `sudo apt install gnome-session gdm3` instead
4. Rebooted to a black screen with blinking carrot

My gut feeling is that I have to install ubuntu-gnome-desktop again, but don't know how to do that since I can't open a terminal from my desktop.

Anyone that can help me out? And also maybe tell me how to correctly install GNOME for Ubuntu Focal

Comment: What was your desktop environment before you tried to install Gnome? Ubuntu comes with Gnome preinstalled. Unless you started with Ubuntu Server.

Comment: Whatever comes with Ubuntu. Didn't know that was gnome...